# Gracefully quit a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am developing a multithreaded application in C#, and I have now come to point where I have realised that my threads sometimes throw errors when I stop them via the `.Abort(); .Join();` methods.

My current code for starting and stopping the thread is as follows:

```
public void StartLogging()
    {
        if (poller != null && poller.IsAlive)
        {
            poller.Abort();
            poller.Join();
        }
        poller = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PollUSBDevice));
        poller.IsBackground = true;
        poller.Name = reference.VendorId.ToString() + ":" + reference.ProductId.ToString();
        poller.Start();
        IsLogging = true;
    }

public void StopLogging()
    {
        if (poller != null && poller.IsAlive)
        {
            poller.Abort();
            poller.Join();
            IsLogging = false;
        }
    }

private void PollUSBDevice()
    {
        ...Removed code - executes within milliseconds and I am not worried about stopping here.

        ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

            ### THIS LOOPS FOR EVER OR UNTIL I CALL .Abort() ###
            while (ec == ErrorCode.None && MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
            {
                if (poller.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.AbortRequested)
                {
                    reader.Abort();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];
                    int bytesRead;
                    ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 100, out bytesRead);

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        new OneArgDelegate(HandleData),
                        new object[] { readBuffer });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Do stuff....
        }
        finally
        {
            Close devices that are running in above while statement
        }
    }
```

I have tried other methods post here on Stackoverflow, however I just can't get my head around them (I'm newish to multithreading). Preferably, there would just be a `bool` switch on my parent object `reference` that I could check. IE:

```
public class Reference
{
    public static bool gracefulStopRequested = false;
}

public void PollUSBDevice
{
     while (ec == ErrorCode.None && !reference.gracefulStopRequested)
     {
         ....
     }
}
```

Can anyone point me to a good resource or give me a hint as to what search terms I should be searching for, or if you are in a  really giving mood, possibly do a mockup of how you would handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread poller = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PollUSBDevice));
        poller.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        StopPoller();

        Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void StopPoller()
    {
        _PollerStopRequested = true;
    }

    private static bool _PollerStopRequested = false;
    private static void PollUSBDevice()
    {
        while (true && !_PollerStopRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("running");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

However this is just simulating a build in feature of C# `BackgroundWorker`, so you could also have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx